# From raw sql query to symfony 2 sql query

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have this sql query:

```
SELECT * from gift WHERE NOW() >= `validbegin` AND NOW() <= `validend` ORDER BY `points`n ASC
```

I need to transform it to a Symfony 2 query to fetch the data to an object call Gift. So far I have this:

```
    $query = $giftRepository->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('NOW() >= validbegin AND NOW() <= p.validend')
        ->orderBy('p.points', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();
    $gifts = $query->getResult();
```

But that gave me:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 53: Error: Expected known function, got
>   'NOW'

Any idea?

ps. Also tried p.NOW()

Comment: what kind of field it is , datetime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$query = $giftRepository->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->where(':now >= validbegin AND :now <= p.validend')
    ->setParameter('now', new \DateTime())
    ->orderBy('p.points', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery();
$gifts = $query->getResult();
```

You generate the field from php, then doctrine will automatically convert it to a mysql timestamp